# Passenger/nginx installation on AIX 5.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, aix

Encounter a peculiar issue while trying to install nginx module through phusion passenger's auto installer. Command is:

passenger-install-nginx-module

Well, this installer tries to run Tar with 'z' flag, which is not supported by AIX 5.3. Is there a lib/package that can upgrade AIX capability to do so? I'm sure there is no way to update the installer to run two separate commands on AIX to unzip the package..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install GNU tar on AIX from http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html - but you'll need to somehow point to the /opt/freeware/bin/tar version.

Comment: Thanks. Below command can be used to point to the GNU Tar:
sudo ln -f -s /opt/freeware/bin/tar /usr/bin/tar

Comment: I wouldn't do that on AIX, too much might rely on the standard AIX version of tar.  Installing the GNU one is fine, but I wouldn't use it for everything.